# How to invoke python script(on linux VM) to run in background from Azure release pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, azure, azure-devops

I am deploying a python code on Linux VM from Azure release pipeline. When I try to start the script from bash task, the task keeps on running. If I try to invoke the scipt start command using nohup, the azure agent kills the process when finishing the task.

```
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/bin/bash'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.
```

Task contents:

```
python3 app/main.py
```

Question:
1.How to run a script in background on linux VM from Azure release pipeline?

2.Is there a specific way to setup this as a process from pipeline on linux VM?

Comment: You can try to open another terminal in the linux VM to execute your python script .Here is a [reference](https://dev.to/gauravpurswani/how-to-execute-commands-from-another-terminals-by-being-on-just-one-terminal-1550) .

Comment: Can you share the python code that you run in task?